# 1.9.2.4 Product.Config label null in US, others working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

We're using Magento 1.9.2.4, Configurable products which has assigned multiple simple products. Each simple product has two attributes, "heel height" and "shoe size". Heel height works as intended, but we're having problem with "shoe size". If we access the store from EU, everything works correctly, but if we access it from US, all shoe size options are shown as "null". Option value is still there, just label is wrong. When I view source from page opened through US, I see this (formatted for easier readability):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var spConfig = new Product.Config({
   "attributes":{
      "133":{
         "id":"133",
         "code":"heel_size",
         "label":"Heel size",
         "options":[
            {
               "id":"21",
               "label":"7.5",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "561",
                  "562",
                  "563",
                  "564",
                  "565",
                  "566",
                  "567",
                  "568",
                  "818",
                  "819",
                  "820",
                  "821",
                  "822",
                  "823",
                  "824"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"9",
               "label":"10",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "569",
                  "570",
                  "571",
                  "572",
                  "573",
                  "574",
                  "575",
                  "576",
                  "825",
                  "826",
                  "827",
                  "828",
                  "829",
                  "831",
                  "832"
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      "134":{
         "id":"134",
         "code":"size",
         "label":"Size",
         "options":[
            {
               "id":"57",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "561",
                  "569"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"45",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "818",
                  "825"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"12",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "562",
                  "570"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"46",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "819",
                  "826"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"13",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "563",
                  "571"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"47",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "820",
                  "827"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"14",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "564",
                  "572"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"48",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "821",
                  "828"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"15",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "565",
                  "573"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"49",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "822",
                  "829"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"16",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "566",
                  "574"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"50",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "823",
                  "832"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"22",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "567",
                  "575"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"51",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "824",
                  "831"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"23",
               "label":null,
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "568",
                  "576"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "template":"\u20ac#{price}",
   "basePrice":"365",
   "oldPrice":"365",
   "productId":"11",
   "chooseText":"Choose a Size ",
   "taxConfig":{
      "includeTax":true,
      "showIncludeTax":true,
      "showBothPrices":false,
      "defaultTax":21,
      "currentTax":21,
      "inclTaxTitle":"Incl. Tax"
   }
});
    </script>
```

If I access the same page through EU, I see this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var spConfig = new Product.Config({
   "attributes":{
      "133":{
         "id":"133",
         "code":"heel_size",
         "label":"Heel size",
         "options":[
            {
               "id":"21",
               "label":"7.5",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "561",
                  "562",
                  "563",
                  "564",
                  "565",
                  "566",
                  "567",
                  "568",
                  "818",
                  "819",
                  "820",
                  "821",
                  "822",
                  "823",
                  "824"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"9",
               "label":"10",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "569",
                  "570",
                  "571",
                  "572",
                  "573",
                  "574",
                  "575",
                  "576",
                  "825",
                  "826",
                  "827",
                  "828",
                  "829",
                  "831",
                  "832"
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      "134":{
         "id":"134",
         "code":"size",
         "label":"Size",
         "options":[
            {
               "id":"57",
               "label":"35",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "561",
                  "569"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"45",
               "label":"35.5",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "818",
                  "825"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"12",
               "label":"36",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "562",
                  "570"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"46",
               "label":"36.5",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "819",
                  "826"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"13",
               "label":"37",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "563",
                  "571"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"47",
               "label":"37.5",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "820",
                  "827"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"14",
               "label":"38",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "564",
                  "572"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"48",
               "label":"38.5",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "821",
                  "828"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"15",
               "label":"39",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "565",
                  "573"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"49",
               "label":"39.5",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "822",
                  "829"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"16",
               "label":"40",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "566",
                  "574"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"50",
               "label":"40.5",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "823",
                  "832"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"22",
               "label":"41",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "567",
                  "575"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"51",
               "label":"41.5",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "824",
                  "831"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"23",
               "label":"42",
               "price":"0",
               "oldPrice":"0",
               "products":[
                  "568",
                  "576"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "template":"\u20ac#{price}",
   "basePrice":"365",
   "oldPrice":"365",
   "productId":"11",
   "chooseText":"Choose a Size ",
   "taxConfig":{
      "includeTax":true,
      "showIncludeTax":true,
      "showBothPrices":false,
      "defaultTax":21,
      "currentTax":21,
      "inclTaxTitle":"Incl. Tax"
   }
});
    </script>
```

As you can see, all option's labels in the US have been turned into "null" values, while EU still shows proper labels. We're not using multistore view, nor multi languages, single store and single language. And out of ideas what could cause this ...

And help and clues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any type of cache or load balancing?

Comment: As far as I know, Redis only.

Comment: Did you perform the usual routine with cache clearing, static content deploy and DI compile?

Comment: Yes, yes and no, this is Magento 1.9, not 2.

Comment: So issue is based on visitor's ip address?

Comment: Presumably yes, since EU IPs do not show this issue, only US does. Note that US is confirmed, we didn't try other countries.

Comment: This is very unusual, i would need to examine code that generates that json to be able to tell you more, but in my experience there is nothing that could produce this kind of problem. Are you sure it's not a client side issue?

Comment: 100% sure, since the above code I pasted is from Chrome's view-source, which is not yet processed by client's side browser. And yes, this is unusual ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the code, I found out that one of previous maintainers added a code to translate the labels. Since this wasn't documented anywhere and backend wasn't updated with this functionality, no one didn't even think of looking into this.

Modified file was found by looking for modified function `getJsonConfig()`, found in `/app/code/local/.../Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php`.